# Python: method of a self-made class doesn't accept a tuple as argument

Tags: python, class

For an assignment I got from school we need to make a chess game. One task is that we need to make a class called chessboard with a couple of methods like place, delete and replace.

My chessboard is a dictionary with the keys as place, in the form of a tuple, and the value as the chess-piece as value. But if I want to give a tuple as argument to my methods it fails.

This is my code:

```
class ChessBoard:
    def __init__(self):
        DICT={ (A,1):None,(A,2):None,(A,3):None,(A,4):None,(A,5):None,(A,6):None,(A,7):None,(A,8):None,
               (B,1):None,(B,2):None,(B,3):None,(B,4):None,(B,5):None,(B,6):None,(B,7):None,(B,8):None,
               (C,1):None,(C,2):None,(C,3):None,(C,4):None,(C,5):None,(C,6):None,(C,7):None,(C,8):None,
               (D,1):None,(D,2):None,(D,3):None,(D,4):None,(D,5):None,(D,6):None,(D,7):None,(D,8):None,
               (E,1):None,(E,2):None,(E,3):None,(E,4):None,(E,5):None,(E,6):None,(E,7):None,(E,8):None,
               (F,1):None,(F,2):None,(F,3):None,(F,4):None,(F,5):None,(F,6):None,(F,7):None,(F,8):None,
               (G,1):None,(G,2):None,(G,3):None,(G,4):None,(G,5):None,(G,6):None,(G,7):None,(G,8):None,
               (H,1):None,(H,2):None,(H,3):None,(H,4):None,(H,5):None,(H,6):None,(H,7):None,(H,8):None }

    def place(self, piece,(row,column)):
        self.piece=piece
        self.(row,column)=(row,column)
        DICT[(row,column)]=self.piece
```

Comment: You need to say explicitly what's not working. And why are trying to make piece, row and column members of the class by prefixing them with `self`?

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating an instance attribute out of your `DICT` attribute in your init. To set it as an *instance* attribute you need to add it to your instance as `self.DICT`

So, your init should looking something like this:

```
# not showing your full dictionary:
def __init__(self):
        self.DICT={ (A,1):None,(A,2):None}
```

Now, in your other instance methods, you simply access accordingly, as an *instance attribute*. You are placing a piece at a location, so you seem like you are wanting to set `self.piece` at `row,column`. Furthermore, I don't know how your other code looks like, but if your `piece` argument you are passing in to your `place` method is only being used in that method, you do not need to set it as an instance attribute.

So, to fix your problem, you can do this:

```
def place(self, piece,(row,column)):
    self.piece=piece
    self.DICT[(row,column)]=self.piece
```

If you in fact are not using `piece` anywhere else in your code, don't set it as an instance attribute, and you can simply do:

```
def place(self, piece,(row,column)):
    self.DICT[(row,column)] = piece
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve,

```
def place(self, piece, row_column_tuple):
  self.piece=piece
  self.row_column_tuple=row_column_tuple
  DICT[row_column_tuple]=self.piece
```

Then elsewhere in the code you can call this method like

```
place(piece, (row, column))
```